# how to remove default key word from emulater when user enter the text in edit text

Tags: android

how to remove default key word from emulater when user enter the text in edit text

Comment: Its desirable to provide more details when you ask a question, many a times one sentence is not enough to figure out the problem.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a default value in edit text that should be changed when user enters some text, and if everything is removed that default text should come

In this case use that default text for hint property of that edit text

Suppose you want your default text 
`Username`

Use this code

```
<EditText
            android:id="id"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_box"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:hint="Enter Username here" />
```